# How to integrate Amazon SDK js and Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, amazon-s3

We need to integrate a image uploader based lightning component with the amazon sdk js library. And due to Locker service I've serious limitations. I've spend all day trying some solutions found in the web using either lightning container or iframe but no luck so far.
Can someone provide me a possible approach for this? Is there some library (or at least a part of the solution)  for the integration of lightning components with a cloud storage service?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many Amazon S3 connectors on the AppExchange. Is it what you need?

Comment: I found several components in AppExchange but we need something more custom because it should be integrated to a implementation which an important number of clients will upload videos and images through a lightning component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we were able to resolve it using an iframe as a bridge between amazon SDK and lightning component. 
Thanks to all

Comment: can you please share some more details around the implementation? This is an accepted answer but does not explain what were your challenges or how you overcome them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using client side SDK you can connect from server side( from Apex).